# Is it possible to use a computer to type a text message, and send that message through bluetooth so that I can send it with my cellphone?

Tags: bluetooth, mobile-phone

I don't have a sophisticated phone, it's a recent Nokia C201, it has the classics: bluetooth, color screen...

Since text messages are a pain to type with the T9 numeric dial buttons, I was wondering if there were any existing softwares/ways to do that...

Using a mac, but if there is something working on PC that'd be nice to know too...

Comment: Google Voice will allow you to send text messages from your computer to your contacts ( provided you import them ) and is platform independent.

Comment: Do you really think it will be simpler to 1) type it out on the computer 2) open the phone and find it from wherever it was stored 3) copy it into the msg field and 4) send it? I very much doubt you will be able to do this in a way that makes life easier rather than needlessly complicated.

Answer (score 1):

### Use [Nokia Suite](http://www.nokia.com/global/support/nokia-suite/)

- [connect mobile via bluetooth](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=SugvjAbLhSg#t=59)
- [text via nokia suite](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=XO47UuqmhOc#t=58)